# Create dataframe with all coefficients from rolling regression

Tags: r, regression, apply, sapply, do.call

I want to create two dataframes that store all intercept and Beta values respectively.

I want each column of the first dataframe to be labelled as "Y1 Intercept", "Y2 Intercept"... "Y(n) Intercept" and then similarly for the second dataframe "Y1 Coef 1", "Y2 Coef 1 and so on and so forth. The naming of columns is important to keep track given that in practice I will implement this code across a much larger dataframe with multiple X coefficients.

Ideally I would also create a third dataframe to store all R-squared values, but hopefully I can figure this point out after help with the above.

```
library(roll)

set.seed(1)
x_var <- data.frame(X1 = rnorm(50))
y_var <- data.frame(y1 = rnorm(50),
                    y2 = rnorm(50),
                    y3 = rnorm(50),
                    y4 = rnorm(50))

#Regression 
model_output <- roll_lm(x = as.matrix(x_var),
        y = as.matrix(y_var),
        width = 12,
        min_obs = 12,
        na_restore = TRUE)


model_output$coefficients
```

The above would give me the output I want, but i'm not sure how to combine all intercept values in a single dataframe and then all Beta values in another with correct column labelling.

Comment: I can use something like this: ```intercept_values <- c()
for(i in 1: length(model_output$coefficients)) {
  intercept_values[[i]] = model_output$coefficients[[i]][,1]}
do.call(cbind,intercept_values) ``` but it seems so inefficient to do something like this

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here's a fairly simple `tidyverse` implementation. The only complicated thing is the column renaming, which uses regex groups:

```
library(tidyverse)
model_output <- as.data.frame(model_output)

rsq_df <- model_output %>%
            select(starts_with("r.squared")) %>%
            rename_with(~str_remove(., "r.squared."))

intercept_df <- model_output %>%
    select(starts_with("coefficients")) %>%
    select(ends_with("Intercept.")) %>%
    rename_with(~ str_replace_all(., "coefficients.y(\\d+)..Intercept.", "Y\\1 Intercept"))

coef_df <- model_output %>%
    select(starts_with("coefficients")) %>%
    select(!ends_with("Intercept.")) %>%
    rename_with(~ str_replace_all(., "coefficients.y(\\d+).X(\\d+)", "Y\\1 Coef \\2"))
```